# Big-oh runtime analysis of the following code

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
public static long A (int N) {
  if (N <= 1) 
    return 1;

  return N + A(N-1) + A(N-2);
}
```

Here is my approach to this: The stack will have N-1 + N-2 calls. Which would just be N + N and would be 2N.

However the answer is 2^N. I don't quite understand that.

Comment: This is almost an identical case of the fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Stack depth is not complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really informal way to think about this.

Let's say N=10. Then 2 calls are made, one with N=9 and one with N=8. For each of those, 2 calls will be made as well, for N=9 one to N=8 and N=7, and for N=8 one to N=7 and N=6.

So whenever N increases by 1, the number of calls is multiplied by 2.

Therefore, O(2^N) is correct.

Comment: Something about the wording had me tripped up and I was about to comment... and then you edited it and made it clearer with `multiplied by 2` - perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `A` generates at most `2` other calls to `A`, where the base case for `N=1` creates constant cost. In total, a call to `A` creates at most a complete binary tree of calls of height `N`, which has

```
sum_{i=0}^{N}2^i = 2^{N+1}-1 in O(2^{N})
```

nodes. More formally, the runtime bound can be obtained by an inductive proof.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can think of it this way:

Complexity(N) = Complexity(N-1) + Complexity(N-2).

Sounds like Fibonacci right?

Complexity(N) = [image]

Thus O(phi^N). where phi=[1+sqrt(5)]/2

Comment: Hooray for the 'closed formula' representation of the Fibonacci sequence!